# What is the smallest block ever mined?

Tags: block, empty-blocks

Has any miner ever earned their 50/25 BTC solving a block with only one or two transactions? Maybe they got lucky before the full ten minutes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thousands of early blocks are empty except for the required generation transaction. See [block #1](http://blockexplorer.com/block/00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048), for example.

Comment: Also, some miners (just to be annoying) mine empty blocks (only containing the 25BTC reward transaction)